Prevent fetch making unwanted requests
fetch is making multiple unwanted requests, I tried the below but it still makes 6 to 10 requests
const [allowParse, setAllowParse] = useState<boolean>(true);
socket.on("upload_finished", function (response) {
        if (allowParse === true) {
            console.log("parse start");
            fetch("start-parse", {method: "POST"});
            setAllowParse(false)
        }
    });

I also looked into this post but I can't use useEffect inside a conditional statement
How do I fix this?
If you are wondering how I receive upload_finished I am using flask socket-io
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def upload_file():
    # Code handling file upload
    socketio.emit("upload_finished")


You cannot use useEffect inside a conditional statement, but you can include the condition in the useEffect callback.

Well I found a workaround but it only works if you are using websockets
Instead of using socket.on("event", () => {"do something"} we can use socket.once

You should wrap the whole socket.on in a useEffect. I can't see why you wouldn't be able to do that, unless you share the entire component file.

Wouldn't useEffect only work when the component (the app in this case) is loaded, but at that time my socket wouldn't emit the upload_finished

socket.on() creates a listener, so it only needs to be registered once. So a useEffect with an empty dependency array would do the job. see this https://github.com/JackMcBride98/rock-paper-scissordle/blob/main/client/src/components/Room.tsx. I've done this before, it's a better way of doing it.
